# HSV and in range method doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem in using the `.inRange()` method in the OpenCV.

I converted the frame to HSV and while I'm using `.inRange()` it doesn't filter correct color.

Can anyone help me?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    while(true){
    Mat input = imread("/home/xenups/Desktop/szpAl.png");
    Mat hsv;
    Mat output;
    cvtColor(input, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(244, 194, 194), Scalar(255, 0, 0), output);
    imshow("ss",input);
    imshow("redOnly", output);
    waitKey(2);
    }
}
```

I used a different scalar color `Scalar(244, 194, 194), Scalar(255, 0, 0)` from [this site](http://www.workwithcolor.com/red-color-hue-range-01.htm) and still I have that problem.

Comment: You use inRange() on your input image not on hsv image!

Comment: @Dennis nope, his usage is correct, overlooking the dodgy scalar values

Comment: In addition to the comments about hue divided by 2: Shouldnt you add some (small) range to the hue channel too???

Comment: i used a different scalar color    Scalar(244 ,194 ,194 ), Scalar( 255 ,0 ,0 ) from 
[enter link description here][1]


and still i have that problem
![enter image description here][2]


  [1]: http://www.workwithcolor.com/red-color-hue-range-01.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your Scalar values are wrong, it has max values of (179,255,255) for hsv images. Use a colour picker to determine the values you need.

Comment: @beaker good point about red-only not being red-only, that was clearly a moment of weakness!